# How to use Gmail to send emails through Google API

Tags: php, email, google-api-php-client, email-client

I am looking for an example code or tutorial for sending Email through Gmail API.

User is able to provide his gmail credentials and authorizing my app to access his compose email option.

But from that point I don't know how to send email.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here describes the case, send an email through gmail account as smtp.
[Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page)

Comment: Nope I am not looking for that. In the example one has to provide username and password to the email client. But in my case user will authorize the app to use their gmail. I am looking for Google API example.

Comment: In that case, look at this
 https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/

Comment: And Google APIs Client Library for PHP (beta) https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/